# Make Plugin publickly in wordpress.org

Tags: wordpress

I created a plugin and then uploaded it to the WordPress.org site, the plugin is Approved by wordpress.org then i commit first comment but message still show:  "This plugin is approved and awaiting data upload but not visible to the public yet. Once you make your first commit, the plugin will become public."

[image]
How can i done it to make publickly

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the change may not happen instantaneously
2. check https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/YOURPLUGIN/ for presence of your files under "trunk" and "tags/YOURVERSION"
3. if your Stable tag (top of your readme.txt) specifies a version as it should do (instead of trunk) then WP org will expect to "serve" you plugin from a directory under "tags".

e.g. if your readme specifies Stable tag: 0.1.0 then **in addition to trunk** you should have also branch taged your files to "/tags/0.1.0/"

Comment: Thank you for support. My plugin is now  show publicly. And my issue is resolved.